# XPath for indexed node in an XML document

Tags: xpath

I have the below document. I am trying to get the `test:Category` at `ABCSite[0]`.
Tried the XPath `$ABCCustomerHierarchy(//ata:ABCSite[0])/test:Customer/test:CustomerID/test:Category`, but I got some XPath exception.

Can anybody tell me the right XPath here please?

```
 <test:ABCCustomerHierarchy xmlns:test="http://wwwin.test.com/testschema">
        <test:ABCSite>
            <test:Customer>
                <test:CustomerID>
                    <test:ID>110984181</test:ID>
                    <test:Category>ABC_Customer</test:Category>
                </test:CustomerID>
            </test:Customer>
            <test:CustomerReferences>
                <test:CustomerID>
                    <test:ID>17808</test:ID>
                    <test:Category>KLM_CUSTOMER</test:Category>
                </test:CustomerID>
                <test:CustomerID>
                    <test:ID>17808</test:ID>
                    <test:Category>XYZ_Customer</test:Category>
                </test:CustomerID>
                <test:CustomerID>
                    <test:ID>17808</test:ID>
                    <test:Category>PQR_CUSTOMER</test:Category>
                </test:CustomerID>
            </test:CustomerReferences>
        </test:ABCSite>
        <test:ABCSite>
            <test:Customer>
                <test:CustomerID>
                    <test:ID>17808</test:ID>
                    <test:Category>XYZ_Customer</test:Category>
                </test:CustomerID>
            </test:Customer>
            <test:CustomerReferences>
                <test:CustomerID>
                    <test:ID>17808</test:ID>
                    <test:Category>PQR_CUSTOMER</test:Category>
                </test:CustomerID>
            </test:CustomerReferences>
        </test:ABCSite>
    </test:ABCCustomerHierarchy>
```

Comment: Please, there is a preview _right below the edit box_. Your code formatting was horribly broken. Also, "some" error message does not help, show _the_ error message you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always specify the namespace (test for your example)

Another point is that arrays start with 1 not zero

If you want to get the value of that node, use text():

```
//test:ABCSite[1])/test:Customer/test:CustomerID/test:Category/text()
```

To match with exact value use:

```
//test:ABCSite[1])/test:Customer/test:CustomerID/test:Category[text()='ABC_Customer']
```

Comment: I tried with namespace only, the issue is if i do comparison like //ABCCustomerHierarchy/ABCSite[1]/Customer/CustomerID/Category = 'ABC'  , 'ABC' is being compared against all the ABCSite at  index [1] of its parent. so i tried $ABCCustomerHierarchy(//test:ABCSite[1])/test:Customer/test:CustomerID/test:Categ‌ ​ory and got the exception : javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens:

Comment: then take everything before [] into brackets. I edided my response

Comment: no worries. you should mark the answer as helpful to help others in future

Comment: Thanks evhen14. There is no error now.  But (//test:ABCCustomerHierarchy/test:ABCSite[1])/test:Customer/test:CustomerID/test:Category = 'XYZ_Customer' return 'true' even if ABCSite[1] holds some other text as Category  . Seems still  it is checking the whole document.

Comment: So, you want it to return false if categories in CustomerReferences differ from XYZ_Customer. In other words, you want that all categories (in CustomerID and in CustomerReferences ) have XYZ_Customer?

Comment: No , I want to return true only if  (//test:ABCCustomerHierarchy/test:ABCSite[1])/test:Customer/test:CustomerID/test‌​:Category = 'XYZ_Customer'  . but its returning true even if (//test:ABCCustomerHierarchy/test:ABCSite[1])/test:Customer/test:CustomerID/test‌​:Category != 'XYZ_Customer'

Comment: i checked the online Xpath tester and this is working perfect there. Seems the issue is with the environment I am using . :(

Comment: I was using ABCSite[$counter] instead of ABCSite[1] where i had initialized counter to '1' . i tried with ABCSite[1] everything works perfect. Thanks a lot enhen14 !

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
//ABCCustomerHierarchy/ABCSite[1]/Customer/CustomerID/Category
```

Comment: No . This is not getting me the node at [0]

Comment: XPath is 1-indexed. There is no element 0. If you want the first, @fastcodejava's solution is the correct one (yet he omitted the namespaces, this could be a problem). Try using _your_ query with namespaces, but index 1.

Comment: I tried with namespace only, the issue is if i do comparison like //ABCCustomerHierarchy/ABCSite[1]/Customer/CustomerID/Category = 'ABC' , 'ABC' is being compared against all the ABCSite at index [1] of its parent. so i tried $ABCCustomerHierarchy(//test:ABCSite[1])/test:Customer/test:CustomerID/test:Cate‌ ​g‌ ​ory and got the exception : javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens: